# AWS Lambda invoke async inside loop, without waiting for future

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm browsing an AmazonMQ queue to find the depth (small 1kb messages), then invoke a lambda for each message to apply some magic.. 
But it seems that the first initial lambda must "live" until the last invoked lambda finishes..

This code doesn't work:

```
InvokeRequest request = new InvokeRequest();
request.setFunctionName("MyLambda");
request.setPayload("{}");

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   lambda.invokeAsync(request);
}
```

Unless I do as stated here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/basics-async.html
and use a `Future<InvokeResult> future_res = lambda.invokeAsync(req);`and wait for each lambda.

But what if execution takes longer than 300s for all lambdas to finish, then I'm in trouble..

Is there a way around this or maybe apply some other design pattern?

**Update**
Seems like setting InvocationType = 'Event' causes async behaviour.. will do more testing

Comment: What is a lambads runtime? What about memory size, did you try to increase that value?

Comment: @AironBrynchke Sems like setting the type to 'event' gives me a runtime of around 10 seconds, as I can start 1000 lambdas at the same time. Before I got 1000 * 10 seconds since they got started synchronously